# Repository is declared with @Repository but bean is not recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot

This has been happening ever since i moved from Spring Data MongoDB to Spring Data Couchbase but even deleting the project as a whole and recreating did not solve the problem.

Every time I start my application throws:

```bash
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.minerva.borrowings.services.BorrowingServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.minerva.borrowings.repositories.BorrowingRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.minerva.borrowings.repositories.BorrowingRepo' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

But my file structure is:

```
 └───com
    └───minerva
        └───borrowings
            │   BorrowingsApplication.java
            │   
            ├───config
            │       LoggingConfig.java
            │       NotificationConfig.java
            │       
            ├───controllers
            │       BorrowingController.java
            │       
            ├───entities
            │       Borrowing.java
            │
            ├───exceptions
            │       BorrowingNotFoundException.java
            │       BorrowingServerErrorException.java
            │       NullBodyException.java
            │       NullIdException.java
            │       UnknownIdTypeException.java
            │
            ├───repositories
            │       BorrowingRepo.java
            │
            └───services
                    BorrowingNotificationSender.java
                    BorrowingService.java
                    BorrowingServiceImpl.java
```

And the repository file is as such:

```java
package com.minerva.borrowings.repositories;

import com.minerva.borrowings.entities.Borrowing;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
   public interface BorrowingRepo extends CouchbaseRepository<Borrowing, String> {
}
```

And my BorrowingApplication.java uses `@SpringBootApplication` and does not allow to use `@ComponentScan` or `@EnableJpaRepository`

My pom.xml file is as such:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.minerva</groupId>
    <artifactId>borrowings</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>borrowings</name>
    <description>borrowings</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried using JpaRepository and CrudRepository but the problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the [`@EnableCouchbaseRepositories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/repository/config/EnableCouchbaseRepositories.html) annotation, maybe even by specifying the `basePackages`. Add a configuration bean like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = "com.minerva.borrowings.repositories")
class CouchbaseDbConfig {
}
```

Comment: I found that a couple of minutes after this post and used it. It resolved it but I got  a timeout exception so I ended up moving back to Mongo.

Comment: @IMNOTIKE with Mongo you get the timeout exception if your connection URL points to non-accessible instance. Are you sure you configured your Couchbase URL correctly?